# Active Appearance Model face for ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, opencv

I am using `OpenCV` to develop an iPhone application, and I am using it to detect faces. Rather than detect the face as a whole, I would like to detect each of the smaller facial features (eyes, nose, ears, lips, etc.). Actually,I want to do something like this [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YjGw0Z_hziE&list=UUfqROL7_ETPYrckx8JoGIVQ)

How to use aam-opencv for iOS?

I searched on internet and I found this [link](https://code.google.com/p/aam-opencv/)

But I don't know how to apply this on iOS.
Please, can you help me about facial expression recognition?